# What's the current state with Application-Level Profile Semantics? Anyone use them?

Tags: rest, web, dsl

Reading books on REST architecture(especially O'Reilly) many times I came across the idea that one should attach data's description into link http header.

```
    Link: <http://example.com/contactmanagement/profile>; rel="profile"
    Date: Fri, 21 Dec 2017 06:47:25 GMT
    Content-Length: ??
    {
    "contactId":1,
    "self":"/contacts/1"
    }
```

Where profile is URI pointing into data description(profile). There are several profile formats:

1. ALPS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Level_Profile_Semantics_(ALPS))
2. Microformats (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat)
3. HAL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language)

It seems that profiles are mostly used in areas of academic researches right now rather then enterprise applications.
I'm wondering does anyone use them?

Answer (score 2):

While this kind of metadata is undeniably useful to a human or a magic self-discovering client, it suffers the same problem as HATEOAS...

Usually you are making millions of identical calls via clients that *already know the data format,* so including human-readable or machine-discoverable links and other metadata needlessly adds to your bandwidth consumption, which tends to cost real money.

Comment: I would even go so far as to say that, contrary to the popular fashion, most clients don't even require a RESTful interface.  They just need a decent JSON API.

Comment: What about scenario when you are building service consumed by independent clients? I mean services located in Internet (non enterprise). In that case API must be documented anyway - are they document it in profile formats?

Comment: I think swagger is widely used : https://swagger.io/solutions/api-documentation/